# How to compare current date with past epoch dates?

Tags: python, calendar, epoch

I would like a way to obtain the milliseconds epoch time of 14 days from whatever the current date might be, not a difference but the complete string.

Never really worked with the time module and unfamiliar with epoch time so not really sure where to start.

```
No code at the moment due to logistical things I may not be considering
```

Ideally, The date that is 14 days in the past would be compared to epoch times in a dictionary and return a result, however I can write the logic for that portion. I am more interested in the logic for getting the proper date in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) module to give you a datetime object that is 14 days ago. The code for that is

```
import datetime
two_weeks_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=14)
```

Once you have a datetime object you can display it in any number of ways. `two_weeks_ago.timestamp()` while give you the unix-epoch timestamp.

Comment: Why do you use 'datetime' twice?

Comment: The first is the name of the module, the second is the name of the class. So the `datetime.datetime.now()` part means: grab the datetime class from the datetime module and call the classmethod now()

Comment: Thank you! do you know how I would then convert two_weeks_ago.timestamp() to an integer variable?

Comment: the timestamp function returns a float so any way to turn a float into an int works. simplest would be `int(two_weeks_ago.timestamp())`